# How to show plot in one window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show a plot in one window instead of opening another window every time I run my PyQT Script.

Here is my code:

```
        fig2 = plt.figure()
        ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
        ax2.add_patch(
            patches.Circle(
                (x1, y1),
                r1,
                fill=False
            )
        )

        ax2.add_patch(
            patches.Circle(
                (x2, y2),
                r2,
                fill=False
            )
        )

        ax2.add_patch(
            patches.Circle(
                (x3, y3),
                r3,
                fill=False
            )
        )
        plt.plot([x_centroid], [y_centroid], 'ro')
        plt.show()
```

Whenever I change my variables,new window pops up.I want it in 1 window.

Comment: There are surely a lot of options to show a plot in a window. This question is completely unclear. Please clearly state the problem you have, what you have done to solve it and in how far it failed. Because this is seemingly a problem with some code you have written, include that in the form of a [mcve]. Also read [ask].

Comment: I used pyplot.show().But when I pass other values it creates more window while I want it to show in one window.

Comment: Which part of the above comment did you not understand?

Comment: I have edited my problem.

Comment: `fig2 = plt.figure()` creates a new figure. So no wonder it shows a new figure if you run that script. Apart it is still unclear how you would like to manage your workflow. How do you run this? What do you mean by "change my variables"?

Comment: "change my variables" refer to the given variables (like x1,y2).I want my workflow to be such that whenever I update the variable,it should'nt plot in new window,rather I want it to be in same window.

Comment: Changing the variable happens inside a text editor I suppose? So then you run the complete script again? This would be a complete new process being created on your operating system, the one process does not know anything about the other. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah as you mentioned above.Sorry new to matplotlib so can't explain it as you want me to.

Comment: I think what the question was really about is how to configure matplotlib to use the plot output device/window in the same manner R does in interactive sessions: It will open a window when the first plot is rendered and reuse it to render subsequent plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no easy way to connect to an existing python process once it is started to run another script within this process.

The option you have is to work in an interactive session, e.g. within IPython. There you may create your plot and manipulate it as you advance.

For example

```
   1: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   2: import numpy as np
   3: fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   4: line, = ax.plot([1,3,2])
   5: plt.ion()
   6: plt.show()                   # shows the figure
   7: line2, = plt.plot([2,2,1])   # inside the figure shows another line
   8: line.remove()                # removes the first line from the figure
```